# How can I create a session storage for my countdown timer so it's not reset after reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer, session-storage

This is my JavaScript file. I use the Countdown.js API , **timer** is a variable I receieve as a parameter.

```
var countDownCompleted = false;
var myCountdownTest = new Countdown({
    time: timer,
    width: 200,
    height: 80,
    onComplete: countdownComplete,
    rangeHi: "minute"
});
function countdownComplete() {
    countDownCompleted = true;
    window.location.href = 'index.php';
}
```

What modification can I do so the countdown does not reset after reloading the page? I don't really understand how to create session storage.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @PatrickHund while I'm by no means going to claim that this is a good question, commenting asking for the OP to provide their code, output and tracebacks on a question where the asker *has* provided their code and that code isn't causing an error (or any text output) seems pretty obviously unhelpful.

Comment: @PatrickHund, it looks like you didn't get what i need. I don't want you to write code for me. My question is clear & I've searched a lot but couldn't solve the problem tho, I just want someone to redirect me to a **thing** that can help me solving it. I said that i don't understand _session storage_ , I said that so someone can provide a good link which i could understand what is it by. Thanks tho for giving your time misunderstanding my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage and sessionStorage work just like normal variables. If you want your timer to pick up where it left off when the page is reloaded, you should store the current value every time the timer goes down.

Then, on every page load, you can check whether there's anything set inside localStorage and, if it is, start back from that value.